# Count duplicate rows for each unique row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `pandas` `DataFrame`:

```
a  b  c
1  s  5
1  w  5
2  s  5
3  s  6
3  e  6
3  e  5
```

I need to count duplicate rows for each unique value of `a` to obtain the following result:

```
a  qty
1  2
2  1
3  3
```

How to do this in `python`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use groupby:

```
g = df.groupby('a').size()
```

This returns:

```
a
1    2
2    1
3    3
dtype: int64
```

EDIT: rename only the single new column of counts.

If you need a new column you can:

```
g  = df1.groupby('a').size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'qty'})
```

to obtain:

```
   a  qty
0  1    2
1  2    1
2  3    3
```

Comment: How to append column names? Imagine that I already have 100 columns. How can I just add a new one 'qty' without manual definition of existing ones?